# Does Vulkan already have multi-threading by default?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am starting a small engine with Vulkan C ++ and I would like to know if it uses the default multi-threading or it must be programmed externally?

Comment: You must use your favorite threading library (like std thread)

Comment: You're probably wondering why your question is downvoted. The simple reason is explained in [ask], in particular it is not really precise. As a rule of thumb, if a question just takes one sentence to explain, there's some more research necessary first. As a new user here, please also take the [tour].

Comment: I asked the question because I did some research that told me that Vulkan was better designed for multi-threading, but I could not find anything in the documentation that said it was already implemented. So, I just wanted to take some information.

Comment: Your question suggests that you're not super experienced in graphics programming, so you should be aware that Vulkan may **not at all** be the API that you want to use, or start with, for that matter. It's very unkind and unforgiving, and not for the faint of heart. Yes, it offers highest performance if you use it _exactly_ right, that's true. But it takes a lot of work to get anything done, and getting it exactly right isn't precisely trivial. Just saying... there's friendlier stuff out there.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, Vulkan does not do things; it provides the means by which *you* can do things. Vulkan doesn't allocate memory; Vulkan allows *you* to allocate memory. Vulkan doesn't enable performance; Vulkan allows *you* to get better performance.

Vulkan does not do threading (for the most part); Vulkan allows *you* to thread your rendering system. It provides the tools needed to allow multiple threads to create sequences of rendering commands independently of each other, and then to communicate these sequences to the GPU in a way that has a single, well-understood execution order (though Vulkan doesn't ensure that a lot of things will respect that order; it allows you to ensure that things which need to respect that order can do so).